# Why backing-field of an static property should be static also?

Tags: c#, static

When I want to use an `private` non-static field in an `public static` property, I have some compiling errors about my `private` non-static field and when I make it `static` also, everything works well.

I don't have well knowledge about compilers, so I want to know why that backing-field also should be `static`?

Comment: This question doesn't require knowledge about *compilers* - it just requires knowledge of the meaning of `static` in C#.

Comment: Thanks Jon. Is there any good resource exactly about `static` modifier in C#? I prefer to know what happens in memory also when playing with `static`.

Comment: Any reasonable C# book or tutorial should explain it. It's pretty fundamental. There's an MSDN page here - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/98f28cdx.aspx - but it's not good to learn a language piecemeal like this; I'd get a good book if I were you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the backing field isn't static, how are you going to obtain an instance for that field when you use it in a static property accessor? Remember that the `static` modifier on a member means that this member is associated with the *type itself*, rather than with a particular *instance* of that type. For a static property to work, it has to have a backing field that is itself static so that it can be implemented accordingly.

It's for the same reason that you can't access any non-static members within static methods without having an instance to work with.